# mysql 5.7.11 revert to myisam

Tags: mysql, wamp

I have installed wamp 3.0.6 and it install mysql 5.7.11. 
But by default, I now end up with MyIsam tables. 
In my.ini, I have default-storage-engine=MYISAM.

Why did it revert back to MyIsam?

The problem is that I'm teaching using WAMP and all my students have this problem. I know that I can simply change the my.ini file or change the var in phpmyadmin, but I wonder why it revert back?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It did not revert back, we intensionally set it back to default to MYISAM as many people were having many problems with corrupted INNODB databases.

A large proportion of WAMPServer users are first time users of all the technologies that make up WAMPServer.

Most never bother to do a database backup, until they get their first corruption.
Most dont bother to close WAMPServer down cleanly, and therefore INNODB can get corrupted more easily than MYISAM.

It was therefore deemed safer for the beginners to default to MYISAM and expect those that now what they are doing to amend the config, or specifically select INNODB in phpMyAdmin when they know that is the table type they want to use